# the statement callback raised an exception phonegap error

Tags: sqlite, cordova

my phonegap code gives me an error "the statement callback raised an exception or statement error callback did not return false" while executing SQL lite queries.

my code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//add listener when device ready
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
var db = window.openDatabase("railway", "1.0", "Railway Ticket", 200000); //will create database Dummy_DB or open it

//function will be called when device ready
function onDeviceReady(){
    db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, isLoggedin);
}

//create table and insert some record
function populateDB(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, email TEXT NOT NULL)');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logedinuser (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT NOT NULL, password TEXT NOT NULL, remember TEXT NOT NULL)');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO users(name,username,password,email) VALUES ("Administrator", "admin", "admin", "admin@gmail.com")');
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO logedinuser(username,password,remember) VALUES ("admin", "admin", "1")');
}

//function will be called when an error occurred
function errorCB(err) {
    alert("Error processing SQL: "+err.code+ " message=" + err.message);
}
function errorCB2(err2) {
    alert("Error processing SQL 2: "+err2.code+ " message=" + err2.message);
}
function errorCB3(err3) {
    alert("Error processing SQL 3: "+err3.code+ " message=" + err3.message);
}

//function will be called when process succeed
function isLoggedin(tx) {
    //alert("success!");
    db.transaction(chklogin,errorCB2);
}

//select all from SoccerPlayer
function chklogin(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM logedinuser',[],lguserresult,errorCB3);
}

function lguserresult(tx,result){
    var nores = result.rows.length;
    if(nores <= '0')
    {
    alert('Please Login or Create new account!');
    }
    else
    {
    $.each(result.rows,function(index){
    var row1 = result.rows.item(index);
    });

    var remember = row1['remember'];
    if(remember == '1')
        {
        window.location.href="index.html";
        }
        else
        {
        alert('Please Login or Create new account!');
        }
    }
}
});
```

Error is at SQL 2. "Error Processing SQL2"

another error is display in log while fetching the data from table in row1 variable.
code:

```
    $.each(result.rows,function(index){
    var row1 = result.rows.item(index);
    });
```

i am new in phonegap, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In your `$(document).ready(function(){}` function call you have defined

```
var db = window.opendatabase(...
```

The `var` keyword makes the variable `db` local to the function. As a result the variable `db` is not visible/available outside the function scope. Therefore the variable `db` inside the function 
`function isLoggedin(tx) {
    //alert("success!");
    db.transaction(chklogin,errorCB2);
}`
is undefined.

You need to make the variable `db` **global**, by removing the `var` keyword. i.e redefine the statement as

```
db = window.opendatabase(....
```

and it should hopefully work.